# Advancements in scientific mind and its side effects on society

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, society, scientific-realism

A *scientific mind* is one that can make the most of observation.

It has highly-refined imagination and curiosity that makes it possible to carry forward advanced research work. And also it's a bit sceptical about its own work as well as of others, enhancing the accuracy in outcomes.

> Also, this is a blend of mind can be developed by anyone. Its not totally related to science or one who studies.

So, with evolution and advancing time, is it possible that the *scientific mind* also has advanced its level of effective observation?

Here are few benefits that I think can be associated with *scientific mind*:

- Its capability to deal with its emotions and working with it, without biasing the results or observations.
- A *scientific mind* can preserve serenity and avoid bias in other arenas in addition to the material world, such as politics and government.

My bigger question is, considering the benefit of the scientific mind, is it possible that it carries some detrimental side effects on society?

Comment: Somethnig along this line has been already poposed by [Francis Bacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Bacon) with his project of a great reformation of knowledge for the advancement of learning called [Instauratio Magna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Works_by_Francis_Bacon#The_Great_Instauration).

Comment: Who were you quoting in "Also, this is a blend of mind can be developed by anyone. Its not totally related to science or one who studies."?

Comment: See Gaston Bachelard, [he Formation of the Scientific Mind : A Contribution to a Psychoanalysis of Objective Knowledge](https://books.google.it/books/about/The_Formation_of_the_Scientific_Mind.html?id=q6-4GAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) (original ed., 1938)

Comment: Could you please clarify a bit what your question is. Your text contains one single sentence with a question mark "is it possible ...?" But I cannot grasp the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: Is it possible....? It means there are chances of side effects of scientific minds on levels of life .

Comment: Please state a well-formed question, thanks.

Comment: I feel the problem is that what people call a 'scientific mind' is often highly unscientific. So much depends on what we mean by the adjective 'scientific' and the question gives only a very vague definition.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is obvious.  The scientific mind **has been advancing** in/with time, and as it has advanced, it has had **tremendous "side effects"** on society (both good and bad).  All you have to do, is study the history of science and or scientists.  Copernicus, Galileo, Newton, Einstein, etc..  Advances in math, physics, cosmology, computers, communications, nuclear power, etc..

Comment: Has the mind been advancing? If so, and if minds and brains are correlated, this should be reflected in the structure of our brains. Is there any evidence that our brains are now noticeably more complex than they were five thousand years ago? I'm not arguing with your point but just wondering. . ,

Answer (score 0):

> My bigger question is, considering the benefit of the scientific mind,
> is it possible that it carries some detrimental side effects on
> society?

[Side effects of scientific mind on levels of life](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51280/side-effects-of-scientific-mind-on-levels-of-life)

From the explanation given above you will understand that the society will become 'lifeless' if we give more importance to the scientific mind.  But fortunately nature never encourages such a situation/society.